# Smali File Syntax

Tags: java, smali

I am trying to get the value of a StringEntity.

In the Java source the StringEntity is declared as

```
this.se = new StringEntity("SomeValue")
```

The Value is encoded via a different function after it has been
declared.

Now I don't have the full source and I am struggling to understand
what to add in the Smali file to get this value of this.se after it
has been changed.

So I know that if I want to create string variable I could

```
new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

const-string v2, "RESULT_DATA "

invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

const-string v3, " Ive added this "

invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
```

I understand what's happening with the above code, but how do I substitute this.se value for v3 ?

I hope it's clear enough for someone to understand.

Regards & Thanks

Potman